# Python CSVkit compare CSV files

Tags: python, csv, csvkit

I have two CSV files that look like this..

**CSV 1**

```
reference  |  name  |  house
----------------------------
2348A      |  john  |  37
5648R      |  bill  |  3
RT48       |  kate  |  88
76A        |  harry |  433
```

**CSV2**

```
reference
---------
2348A
76A
```

Using Python and CSVkit I am trying to create an output CSV of the rows in CSV1 by comparing it to CSV2.  Does anybody have an example they can point me in the direction of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommended to use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) to achieve what you are looking for:

And here is how simple it would be using pandas, consider your two csv files are like this:

> **`CSV1`**

```
reference,name,house
2348A,john,37
5648R,bill,3
RT48,kate,88
76A,harry ,433
```

> **`CSV2`**

```
reference
2348A
76A
```

> **Code**

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'd:\temp\data1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'd:\temp\data2.csv')
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on= 'reference', how='inner')
df3.to_csv('outpt.csv')
```

> **output.csv**

```
,reference,name,house
0,2348A,john,37
1,76A,harry ,433
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a tool like;

- **csvjoin** from **csvkit** or
- **Pandas**

---

**Solution 1:**

```
pip install csvkit
$ csvjoin --help
usage: csvjoin [-h] [-d DELIMITER] [-t] [-q QUOTECHAR] [-u {0,1,2,3}] [-b]
               [-p ESCAPECHAR] [-z MAXFIELDSIZE] [-e ENCODING] [-S] [-v] [-l]
               [--zero] [-c COLUMNS] [--outer] [--left] [--right]
               [FILE [FILE ...]]
```

**Example:**
**Left** Join on **column** of [reference]

```
csvjoin --columns "reference" --left CSV1.csv CSV2.csv
```

---

**Solution 2:**

You can also use the **pandas** library which is easier to **manipulate** Dataframe and filter by column.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('CSV1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('CSV2.csv')

df = df1[df1['reference'].isin(df2['reference'])]
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```